How to correctly specify "exposure" and "outcome" in dagitty/ggdag, when modelling the inverse relationship (exposure ~ outcome)?
I am trying to use the package ggdag in R to better understand the results of my modelling.  If I wish to model the relationship response ~ event I can easily find which variables to control for:
library(ggdag)

dagify(
  response ~ event + confounder,
  event ~ confounder,
  exposure = c("event"),
  outcome = c("response")
) |> ggdag_adjustment_set()


However, if I am now interested in modeling the reverse relationship, that is event ~ response (for example, to predict the probability of event given response), I get a warning saying that it is not possible to close backdoor paths:
dagify(
  response ~ event + confounder,
  event ~ confounder,
  exposure = c("response"),
  outcome = c("event")
) |> ggdag_adjustment_set()
#> Warning in dag_adjustment_sets(., exposure = exposure, 
   outcome = outcome, : Failed to close backdoor paths. 
   Common reasons include:
#>             * graph is not acyclic
#>             * backdoor paths are not closeable with given set of variables
#>             * necessary variables are unmeasured (latent)


The same happens in an even simpler DAG:
dagify(
  response ~ event,
  exposure = c("response"),
  outcome = c("event")
) |> ggdag_adjustment_set()

It appears to me that since the direction of causation is event -> response the path I am asking for (response -> event) is interpreted by ggdag as a backdoor path, hence the warning.
Since my actual model is much more complex than these simple examples, I would still like to get an adjustement set from ggdag.
What would be the correct specification of the DAG? Should one just leave the "exposure" and "outcome" as in the first case, even if modelling in the reverse direction?

The ggdag package provides tools for building causal models, not statistical models. Specifically, the ggdag_adjustment_set() function identifies an adjustment set to determine the causal effect of a specified exposure on a specified outcome, based on the given graph. It does not perform variable selection for statistical models. If I understand correctly, you want to build a statistical model for the "exposure" and include the "outcome" as potential covariate. If that’s the case, ggdag won't be useful for this task because it involves predicting the past using the future, which is inherently non-causal. You should explore other methods and libraries for variable selection and model comparison.
